# Probability with near infinite possibilities

Tags: probability, statistics

I am currently playing a game that lets you breed horses of 4 different tiers. You can only buy horses of the first tier and by combining two horses of the same tier you may get the horse of the next tier. However when breeding you will always get just 1 horse back. When breeding the chances are as follows:

- 20% to advance to the next tier
- 30% to get the next lower tier horse
- 50% to get a horse with the same tier back

You can never breed two tier 1 horses and get a lower tier horse back as tier 1 is already the lowest tier. For simplicity we say that the price for buying a tier 1 horse is 10 gold.

Now to my question:
How can I calculate the chance to get a horse of the highest tier based on a limited amount of money. For example:
How high is the chance to get a horse of tier 4 if I have 100 gold to spend?

Comment: So if you breed two tier $1$ horses you have $80\%$ chance to get a tier $1$ and $20\%$ chance to get a tier $2$?

Comment: Does it cost anything to breed the horses?  Can you breed them indefinitely?  If you can breed them over and over again, the probability is $1$.

Comment: @saulspatz:  I assumed that each time you pair them you lose the starting pair, so you have one less horse afterward.

Comment: @Ross Milikan yes for the first tier you have a 80/20 probabillity and your assumtion further below is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way, but starting with just $10$ horses the casework is not so bad.  A few more horses will make it much worse.

You have five pairs of level $1$ and need to get at least $4$ level $2$ horses.  You have $0.2^5$ chance of getting $5$ and $5\cdot 0.2^4 \cdot 0.8 + {5 \choose 3} \cdot 0.2^3 \cdot 0.8^2 \cdot 0.2$ chance of getting $4$, where the first term has four successes in the first five and the second has three successes of the first five plus a success from pairing the two that came from failures.

If you have just four tier $2$ horses you need three successes, so the chance is $0.2^3$.  If you have $5$, your chance to get two level $3$ horses is $0.2^2+2 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.2$ where the first has success in the first two pairings and the second has one success and one break even, then success with the last horse.  Then you have $0.2$ chance for the last pairing.

Overall we then have $$0.2^5\left(0.2^2+2 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.2\right)\cdot 0.2+\left(5\cdot 0.2^4 \cdot 0.8 + {5 \choose 3} \cdot 0.2^3 \cdot 0.8^2 \cdot 0.2\right)\cdot 0.2^3\\
=0.2^6\cdot0.08+0.01664\cdot 0.2^3\\=0.00013824$$
or about $1$ in  $7234$

Comment: In the first expression, $5\cdot 0.2^4 \cdot 0.8 + {5 \choose 3} \cdot 0.2^3 \cdot 0.8^2 \cdot 0.2^2$, I'm not sure the exponent on the last $.2$ is correct.  Don't we have $3$ successes, two failures, and then **one** success?

Comment: @saulspatz:  Yes, that is right.  Fixed.  That almost doubled the chance.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\{X_n : n=0,1,2,\ldots\}$ by $X_0=1$ and $\mathbb P(X_{n+1} = j\mid X_n = i)$ by the $(i,j)^{\mathrm{th}}$ entry of 
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
4/5&1/5&0&0\\
3/10&1/2&1/5&0\\
0&3/10&1/2&1/5\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here we are assuming that we do not breed horses once they reach tier $4$. Let $\tau = \inf\{n>0: X_n = 4\}$. We want to find $\mathbb P(\tau_4 \leqslant G-1)$, where $G$ is the amount of gold to spend. (It is $G-1$ because the first time we breed horses we must purchase two, and every time afterwards only one). Now, $\{X_n\}$ is an absorbing Markov chain since $P_{44}=1$, so we may write
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}T&T^0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $T$ is the substochastic matrix corresponding to transitions between transient states:
$$
T = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{4}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 \\
 \frac{3}{10} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{5} \\
 0 & \frac{3}{10} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
and $T^0 + T\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$, where $\mathbf 1$ is the column vector consisting of $1$'s. The distribution function of $\tau$ is $F(n) = 1 - T^n\mathbf 1$. Hence $\mathbb P(\tau\leqslant G-1\mid X_0=1)$ is the first entry of $1-T^{G-1}\mathbf 1$, which is
$$
\frac{10^{-G} \left(40 \left(20 \sqrt{3}-23\right) \left(8-\sqrt{3}\right)^G+61\ 2^G \left(33\ 5^G-5\right)-40 \left(20 \sqrt{3}+23\right) \left(\sqrt{3}+8\right)^G\right)}{2013}.
$$
For $G=100$ this is
$$
\frac{115531207184449084522237274383280936365700254333259066124619777053599710798783917531434183122827301}{125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}\approx 0.9242497.
$$
Note that $\tau$ is known as a **phase-type distribution**.